# Why can't I save a session variable in Flask in an if statement?

Tags: javascript, session, flask, axios

My understanding of session in Flask is that you can save it anywhere, to access it anywhere. Except, it's not being saved. I am using axios.get to get multiple variables from my script in my jinja file. Only way I can figure out how to set multiple is to do another axios call after a delay.

I've been trying to figure this out for like 4 hours now, and nothing I do works. I originally had it without /saved and did "the work" in the getmethod route, but then I realized it does the work every time axios.get is called in JS. I've tried using global variables as in global x, x = jsdata, and then outside of if doing session['name'] = x...but it says x is not defined.

EDIT: Just tried session.modified = True, and it still didn't work.

My code:

**JS**

```
btn = document.querySelector('.btn')
let newBoard = '';
btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    
    
    newB()

axios.get(`/getmethod/${newBoard}`)
axios.get(`/getmethod/${clk.innerHTML}`)
axios.get(`/getmethod/${solved}`)
alert("You saved the game!")
setTimeout(() => {
    axios.get('/saved')
}, 1000);
})

function newB() {
    let board = document.querySelectorAll('input')

    for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {

        if (board[i].value === '') {
            newBoard += '0'
        }
        else {
            newBoard += board[i].value
        }
    }
    return newBoard
}
```

**Flask**

```
@app.route('/getmethod/<jsdata>')
def get_javascript_data(jsdata):
    """Gets clock/board from javascript to save a game if logged in"""

    if len(jsdata) == 81:
        if "0" in jsdata:
            session['board'] = jsdata
        else:
            session['solved'] = jsdata

    if jsdata == "Easy" or jsdata == "Medium" or jsdata == "Hard":
        session['level'] = jsdata

    if ":" in jsdata:
        session['clock'] = jsdata

    return jsdata

@app.route('/saved')
... works with variables set in route above
...level = session.get('level', None)
...print(level) DOES NOT equal what was set in route above
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't figured out what was going on with the session not saving as I expected it too, but I did figure out a solution using axios post, instead of just axios get.